# How many different variations of iPhone 5c are in the US market?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are 5 colors variations for the iPhone 5c, each has 2 different memory sizes.

Each of color/memory combination is sold in additional 5 variants:
three simlocked (AT&T, Sprint and Verizon) and two SIM unlocked (one with a T-mobile card, the other without a SIM card).

How many differents SKUs of iPhone 5c Apple has to import from their Chinese factories?

Comment: (I hope that I am in topic here... I mean, it's a math problem)

Comment: $5\cdot 2 \cdot 5=50$ is a good upper bound.

Comment: Oops, looks like I'm off topic :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As each category is separate, one could just multiply these together:

$5*2*5=50$

You could enumerate all the possibilities if you wanted since it is a rather small amount.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking that simply multiplying them was a wrong approach